# how to make some border lines of a table thick and colored

Tags: tables, color, border

how to make some border lines of a table thick and colored (either vertical lines or horizental lines)?I tried Xcline but could not color it. Also I tried make the cline thick but failed.

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{green}

\begin{tabular}{
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 l
 |
 c
 !{\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt}
 c
 ||
}
 one & two & three\\
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3\\%
\noalign{
\color{yellow}
\hrule height 5pt
}%
4&5&6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As usual I'm impressed by your answer. I also hope that the example was meant to discourage the questioner's design idea.

Comment: @PeterWilson oh now I'm hurt, I thought it was an example of a pinnacle of typographic design:(

Comment: Further, How to just make parts of border lines thick and colored.

Comment: If I'm trying to color the last line of the table using the same syntax, the red vertical line goes beyond the last horizontal line. How can I solve it ?

Comment: @EisenHeim please don't ask new questions as comments on old answers, that means you have an error somewhere, perhaps you have `\\ ` after the line.

Answer (score 0):

With `nicematrix`, you can draw rules with all the characteristics of lines of TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|[tikz={very thick,blue}]cc}
\Hline[tikz={very thick,red}]
one & two & three \\
four & five & six \\
seven & eight & nine 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Of course, you can define your own short-cuts with `\newcommand` and `\newcolumntype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\newcommand{\ThickHline}{\Hline[tikz={very thick,red}]}
\newcolumntype{I}{|[tikz={very thick,blue}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cIcc}
\ThickHline
one & two & three \\
four & five & six \\
seven & eight & nine 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

However, `nicematrix` provides also a key to define in a comprehensive way tools for your personal style of rules (with the ability to define a command similar to `\cline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       command = ThickHline ,
       ccommand = ThickNCLine ,
       letter = I ,
       tikz = { very thick, blue }
     }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cIcc}
\ThickHline
one & two & three \\
four & five & six \\
\ThickNCLine{2-3}
seven & eight & nine 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Eventually, it's possible with the tools of `nicematrix`, to draw with TikZ whatever rule you want but using the PGF/TikZ nodes created by `nicematrix` under the cells, rows and columns of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|ccc}
one & two & three \\
four & five & six \\
seven & eight & nine 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [very thick, blue] (2-|2) -- (3-|3) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the last code]