# Vertical line tabularx too long

Tags: color, tabularx, colortbl, hhline

I've seen this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391491/28926), and I've tried to reproduce it.

My goal is to have all the table borders red and some of them thick.
But the 2 first vertical lines span beyond the last horizontal rule, and I don't see where it fails.

[image: MWE output]

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{green}

\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 c
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 l
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 X
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
}
\noalign{
    \color{red}
    \hrule height 2pt
}%
  1 & 2 & 3\\
\noalign{
\color{red}
\hrule height 2pt
}%
    4 & 5 & 6\\
\noalign{
    \color{red}
    \hrule height 2pt}% 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet the requirement?

Thickness can be varied as per choice

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{red}

\begin{tabular}{
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 l
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 c
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
 c
 !{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}
}
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3\\%
\noalign{
\color{red}
\hrule height 2pt
}%
4&5&6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. For completeness's sake, here's the command to increase the thickness of the horizontal lines : `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}` (from the colortbl doc).