# table with optional border colors and text colors

Tags: tables, color, border

I am trying to make a table that has a can have optional color for its borders and texts, similar to the following table taken from [here](https://www.attoworld.de/fileadmin/user_upload/tx_attoworld/publications/thesis_phd_en_Y2015_M01_D15_LMU_FakPhys_FattahiHanieh.pdf).

I hadn't very much luck so far modifying the snippets available on internet to come up with something similar. Can anyone suggest a simple snipped example?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? If you add `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to your preamble, you can use `\textcolor` for colored text and `\arrayrulecolor` to change the color of the lines in the table.

Comment: @leandriis I first tried the answer here for the borders :https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391469/how-to-make-some-border-lines-of-a-table-thick-and-colored/391491 but it was quite fragile and didn't compile with any change I was making( e.g., removing the right side border)

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
 & text & text & text \\
\hline
\textcolor{green}{text} & text & text & text\\
\hline
text & text & text & text\\
\hline
\textcolor{purple}{text} & text & text & text\\
\hline
\textcolor{blue}{text} & text & text & text\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}` should get you started. Personally, I'd however recommend a table layout with less color and less lines.

Comment: @leandriis Sorry to ask, you are answering more questions in a better manner, but most of the time in `comment` only, if you make those as answer, then it will use for future users....Sorry if bother...

Comment: @leandriis worked, I can accept it as a correct answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` in the preamble of you document, you can use

```
\textcolor{<color name>}{<text>}
```

to change the color of the tex and

```
\arrayrulecolor{<color name>}
```

to change the color of all lines in the following table.

For `<color name>` you can either use the predefined colors that come with the various color models of the `xcolor` package or an own color you prviously defined using the `\definecolor`  command.

A very simple MWE that should help get you started looks like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document} 
\arrayrulecolor{blue} 
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}  
& text & text & text \\ 
\hline 
\textcolor{green}{text} & text & text & text\\ 
\hline 
text & text & text & text\\ 
\hline 
\textcolor{purple}{text} & text & text & text\\ 
\hline 
\textcolor{blue}{text} & text & text & text\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it more similar also to the first image in terms of font or spacing sizes?

Comment: @Azerila: For a sans serif font, you can use `\sffamily`, for more vertical white space between horizontal lines and the text in the cells, you can take a look at the `cellspace` package, and for wider columns, you could use the `wc{<width>}` column type from the `array` package.